# spring i18n LocaleResolver getLocale

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, internationalization

dealing with spring i18n. I have defined two beans in `spring-mvc.xml`

```
<bean name="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean name="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

and two anchors in jsp to switch languages

```
<span>
    <a href="?lang=en">english</a>
    | 
    <ahref="?lang=zh">chinese</a>
</span>
```

I tried to get the parameter `lang/locale` at my controller and i18n the results before javascripts *(because I want to i18n java script)*, but doesn't work.

```
request.getLocale().getDisplayName();
request.getParameter("lang");
```

how do I get the `Locale` at my controller? or any good idea to i18n java scripts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you want to change to another Locale, in Java, you can use:

String anotherLocale="es";
RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request,response, anotherLocale);

Comment: Another version: 

Locale locale = new Locale("es");
RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, locale);

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Spring Web MVC parameter reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-arguments

> Supported method argument types
>   ...
>   `java.util.Locale` for the current request locale, determined by the most specific locale resolver available, in effect, the configured `LocaleResolver` in a Servlet environment.

This means that you can simply use `java.util.Locale` argument in your Controller method, and a currently-resolved locale will be assigned to this argument by Spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{viewName}", method = GET)
public String handle(@PathVariable String viewName, Locale locale) {
    return "info/" + locale.getLanguage() + '/' + viewName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
public class MyController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        Locale locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request);
        System.out.println("Locale >>> " + locale);
    }
}
```

---

result:

```
Locale >>> en
```